# Node.js - How to Upload an MP4 to Twitter

Tags: node.js, twitter, media

I'm currently learning how to make a Twitter bot with *Node.js*, and I can't figure out how to upload an *mp4* to Twitter.

I have searched around on Google and YouTube on how but it just seems to either give me more errors or just seem to not be needed for how I have done it.

Now, I am new to *Node.js* so forgive me if I seem to be mistaking basic things.

Here is my current code:

```js
const Twit = require('twit'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path'),
  config = require(path.join( __dirname, 'config.js') );




async function main() {
  const T = new Twit( config );

  T.post('statuses/update', {
    status: 'File time lezgo',
    media: "./media/congrats.mp4"
  }, function( err, data, response ) {
    console.log( data )
  } );
}

console.log("Starting the bot...");

setInterval(main, 5000)
```

If anyone has an explanation on how to do it or if I am missing something then please do let me know, as I - like I said - am new to *Node.js* and the Twitter API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly attach Media to your tweet, you have to first upload the media and use the returned `media_id` in the `statuses/update` endpoint

Following example is taken from [twit lib](https://github.com/ttezel/twit#usage) itself (little bit cleaned though)

```
let b64content = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/media', {
    encoding: 'base64'
})

// first we must post the media to Twitter
T.post('media/upload', {
    media_data: b64content
}, (err, data, response) => {

    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    // now we can assign alt text to the media, for use by screen readers and
    // other text-based presentations and interpreters
    let mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string
    let altText = "This is an ALT text"
    let meta_params = {
        media_id: mediaIdStr,
        alt_text: {
            text: altText
        }
    }

    T.post('media/metadata/create', meta_params, (err, data, response) => {
        if (!err) {
            // now we can reference the media and post a tweet (media will attach to the tweet)
            let params = {
                status: 'File time lezgo',
                media_ids: [mediaIdStr]
            }

            T.post('statuses/update', params, (err, data, response) => {
                console.log(data)
            })
        }
    })
})
```

This can be further cleaned up by using `async/await` but for now this should work

**Update**

For .mp4 type of files you will have to use `postMediaChunked` method

```
let filePath = '/absolute/path/to/file.mp4'

T.postMediaChunked({
    file_path: filePath
}, (err, data, response) => {

    if (err) {
        cosnole.error(err);
    }

    let mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string;

    let params = {
        status: 'File time lezgo',
        media_ids: [mediaIdStr]
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', params, (err, data, response) => {
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. When I run the bot, I get an error which says that the media type is unrecognised.

Comment: What is the media type that you are uploading, and what are you setting it to in the API call?

Comment: mp4, and I'm not too sure. I'm new to Node.js.

Comment: @SlendertheBlender Check the update, Added the code for .mp4 file type

Comment: It's now outputting error 324 `Not valid video`. I did some research and found that means: **Corresponds with HTTP 400. There was a problem with the media ID submitted with the Tweet.**. Sorry for all of these and not fixing it myself, I would but I'm not too confident with Node.js.

Comment: @SlendertheBlender You will have to check your video file, as there are certain restrictions that might prevent video from getting uploaded. Check the [restrictions here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices) - Section `Video specifications and recommendations`